# PactBroker throws java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)

Tags: java, unit-testing, pact, pact-broker

I have a pact broker server hosted at https://mytestbroker.com. I am able to browse the broker page.

When I run `mvn test`, the contract test fails with Connection timed out error.

```
curl -i https://mytestbroker.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/hal+json;charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 06 Jan 2021 03:40:58 GMT
Server: nginx/1.13.12
Status: 200 OK
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Pact-Broker-Version: 2.29.0
X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger 6.0.2
Content-Length: 2648
Connection: keep-alive


@PactBroker(host = "mytestbroker.com", scheme = "https", consumers = {"my-api"})
@Provider("backend1")
public class MyContractTest {
  @State("do some action")
  public void testBackendService1() {    
  }
}

org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to mytestbroker.com:443 [mytestbroker.com/2.2.2.2, mytestbroker.com/5.5.5.5] failed: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems unrelated to Pact, and more about networking.

Is the broker publicly accessible? How is the test itself run? Are their intermediate proxies that cURL knows about that the Java process doesn't?

You should enable debug level logging to see what Pact sees.

Comment: Yes it is publicly available. No proxies used on both curl and Java.

Comment: Is it the URL from above? That doesn't work for me

Comment: Also please share debug level logging from your Java process that's failing so we can diagnose. At the moment we can only point to generic solutions

Comment: It's been almost two weeks and I am still stuck. 

mytestbroker.com is a bogus URL endpoint. My code snippet above illustrates that my broker endpoint is accessible via CURL or the browser, just not via the provider plugin.

I have tried all manners of testing, including using a docker container, a different VM and even a different physical development machine but to no avail. I have decided to abandon Pact and will consider after frameworks.

Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Perhaps it's worth jumping in our slack channel slack.pact.io and sharing some detail there? Your issue seems likely to do with configuration in your pact broker / environment, we just need to get to the bottom of that.

Comment: Quick update. The issue is a networking, not the pact provider plugin.

Comment: Digressing here. The pact product is unnecessarily convoluted, complex and simply require hours and hours of troubleshooting just to get anything done.  The documentation itself doesn't help much in troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. What was the networking issue? Sorry to hear about your experience, if there was any specific feedback you're willing to share please either a) raise a github issue or b) let us know in our slack channel (slack.pact.io)

Comment: No idea at this point. My test unit was able to connect to the free starter pact broker endpoint, not the internal pact broker. However, the internal pact broker is accessible via the browser and CURL. It is definitely networking issue but not sure what it is. Double checked on proxy settings, there's none.

Running a local pact broker on docker works as well.